# How to get view for each article?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 4 tables

```
articles
category
article_category
view
```

I need to find view count for each article
Below is my sql query

```
SELECT a.id,
(SELECT SUM(view) FROM view v ON v.aid=a.id) as view 
FROM articles a JOIN article_category ac ON a.id 
ON ac.aid JOIN category c ON c.id=ac.cid 
LEFT JOIN view cv ON v.aid=a.id GROUP BY a.id
```

My guestion is if there are another ways without using extra SELECT query?

Comment: What does category and article_category have to do with it? It looks like you just need article and view?

Comment: articles belongs to categories one article can belong more than 1 category  i use category table on join cause i check category status etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply need to take the sum out of the subquery and use it.

```
Select a.ID,SUM(cv.view)
FROM articles a 
JOIN article_category ac ON a.id = ac.aid 
JOIN category c ON c.id=ac.cid 
LEFT JOIN view cv ON v.aid=a.id GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: i one article belongs to category it does not worki get duplicates